# Angular animation fade-in on page-load

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-animations

**In Angular 5, in the following example, how can I achieve a staggered animation of the `<h1>` and `<p>` on page-load?**

Goal: When the page loads, fade-in the headline, then fade-in the introduction.

HTML:

```
<div class="header" [@header]>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Introduction</p>
</div>
```

TS:

```
trigger( 'header', [
    transition( ':enter', [
        query( '*', stagger( '300ms', [
              animate( '.3s ease-in', keyframes([
                style( { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-15%)', offset: 0}),
                style( { opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1}),
              ]))
          ]), { optional: true} ),
      ] )
  ] ),
```

As is, the problem appears to be that `<h1>` and `<p>` start with an `opacity` of `1` by default. So what appears to be happening is they get faded out first, and then get faded back in.

If I use css to set their `opacity` to `0` manually, the start of the animation appears to work correctly, but they get hidden from the page as soon as the animation is over.

What do I need to do to get this to work as desired?

Comment: Before your `animate` write `style({ opacity: 0 })`. It defines the style before the animation starts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best case is to set the initial style then reveal by stagger animation

```
trigger('header', [
    transition(':enter', [
      query('*', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-15%)' })),
      query('*', stagger('300ms', [
        animate('.3s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)'}))
        ]))
      ])
    ])
```